# Kibana server is not ready yet using docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I run the elasticsearch and kibana version 8.7.0
the first time it is ok
but when I run it the second time  I test the kibana in the browser I had this problem :
`Kibana server is not ready yet.`

when I tap this command `docker inspect logs kib-01`
this is what I have :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809",
        "Created": "2023-06-01T11:06:59.470910111Z",
        "Path": "/bin/tini",
        "Args": [
            "--",
            "/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 7315,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-06-09T11:17:09.677908307Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-06-09T11:16:32.754950201Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a96c64a53cfef6942fa8c154d082b360d8e054d13c44df622d9197df63efea8e",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809/cbcd8738b89cd17c597f94d2fcd22e84bc874374f59ec0c1eb35668ef6256809-json.log",
        "Name": "/kib-01",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "elastic",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5601/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5601"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                30,
                152
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acfd1b8293740783a8e46b04bd5b0a5d08a86941e562a37fe1b29dee50284ffd-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a390e5157e43919076bff5e21d7926b89690ff8cd22e8245a9ee1d6806faef72/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4809c9c68657b3221c231315d87b12fea6680d7e35ee0c52a3cb4c07a5b2b183/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/006770f90bf7dc15f53479f042e48539bf2f00af205e522feb943ccc172bef52/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b57803d49f2672808b24bbc10613cabe9595b17846979f8d51f0be387b39102/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ff7174d05361d984a2e5a0ab2d222541171ed9fe7413bd84cab525052781d74e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1cfb2d18535e0c3486b29f5b3dcf4b868f9ae577eb71c5bd8ef51653c899ec82/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8458e3c38229b98f58840424e11ab406889b529dfcf70edc68516dcbd0533788/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e4adaf29cfd9706182be0374b63f3aa89038fb081b078b54c4a2fee506b2133d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ba1928e38cbb4a632580b79fc2bc396b4f5aac2959f315c9e3a09df838b66d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ba3f5e02b7d3a0f5b92ebad05870b8e283901c0ec387ccfa9e94d54516cd32/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/30a25241d262185f00b53733cbf09d0782469ba4dea4c4e6e0e24c29b9f50d75/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/384b6dde7e6597cf6a7fb41a0b092abf0e0789ac8f333167a89d43e1f2ef6a5c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2df86685b93c5a2dc3c89aafe56215634473039e37c52a9900260bb6191f49f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b90cd745acd246603e82cafe8aa7053baa3eeaac8104029b8a60972f3e60b3f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ee80ff4491e0dc082955762d72fa457e24acb12a09f0d9494951ea411ffefb9/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acfd1b8293740783a8e46b04bd5b0a5d08a86941e562a37fe1b29dee50284ffd/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acfd1b8293740783a8e46b04bd5b0a5d08a86941e562a37fe1b29dee50284ffd/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acfd1b8293740783a8e46b04bd5b0a5d08a86941e562a37fe1b29dee50284ffd/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "cbcd8738b89c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "kibana",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5601/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/share/kibana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ELASTIC_CONTAINER=true"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"
            ],
            "Image": "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.0",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/kibana",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/tini",
                "--"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "2023-03-27T11:09:20.771Z",
                "org.label-schema.license": "Elastic License",
                "org.label-schema.name": "Kibana",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.url": "https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana",
                "org.label-schema.usage": "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/reference/index.html",
                "org.label-schema.vcs-ref": "05f12599523732051b84dde0b8d5610e0db2b06d",
                "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/elastic/kibana",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "Elastic",
                "org.label-schema.version": "8.7.0",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2023-03-27T11:09:20.771Z",
                "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/reference/index.html",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Elastic License",
                "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
                "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "05f12599523732051b84dde0b8d5610e0db2b06d",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/elastic/kibana",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Kibana",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana",
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Elastic",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "8.7.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "4039d0a16e69eb1960b89d9dceb7cb0accedcb0834ab54c307e44ea1f8906c85",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5601/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5601"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/4039d0a16e69",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "elastic": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "cbcd8738b89c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "efb8507c6ec66ecd0e54a2fa0c0807358626ac17018e1bb078743bd2f61b407a",
                    "EndpointID": "2e3a626e7d9e327e6a17edea80989609d3d4bda86408555f595c46af6372af18",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
Error: No such object: logs
```

what is the problem ?? I work on docker-desktop on Windows 11

Comment: `docker inspect logs` is not a valid command, you can either `docker inspect --type container|image|node|network|secret|service|volume|task|plugin` or `docker logs containername`. Here you should check the logs of the container so run `docker logs kib-01` and update your question with the logs.

Comment: Can you also clarify your question? As far as I understand you are using Elasticsearch Docker-Cluster? If it is so, are you running Kibana and Elasticsearch in one `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: no I use docker-desktop  I run elasticsearch and kibana without using docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

That what i have when I tape this command :
docker logs kib-01

```
[2023-06-01T11:07:27.109+00:00][INFO ][node] Kibana process configured with roles: [background_tasks, ui]
```

[2023-06-01T11:08:26.686+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "cloudChat" is disabled.
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.689+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "cloudExperiments" is disabled.
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.689+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "cloudFullStory" is disabled.
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.690+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "cloudGainsight" is disabled.
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.698+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "profiling" is disabled.
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.804+00:00][INFO ][http.server.Preboot] http server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.883+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Setting up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.886+00:00][INFO ][preboot] "interactiveSetup" plugin is holding setup: Validating Elasticsearch connection configuration…
[2023-06-01T11:08:26.921+00:00][INFO ][root] Holding setup until preboot stage is completed.

i Kibana has not been configured.

Go to http://0.0.0.0:5601/?code=435483 to get started.